# Access xml from ISBNDB

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have a java client and I try to get the `XML DOM` object from ISBNDB by passing the ISBN number of book. But I get `null` as the result. But I am able to get the xml when I hit the URL from my browser. Am I doing it in the right way? or Am I completely on a wrong track?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
try {
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myproxy");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new URL("http://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?access_key=MYKEY&index1=isbn&value1="+isbnValue).openStream());
    System.out.println(doc.getTextContent());
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```